# Показывать блок при наведении на класс

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть код а в нем ссылка и див блок, находятся [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/CN5m2/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<span class="test">Тест</span>

<div class="block">
    Lorem.....
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.db {
    display:block;
}
.dn {
    display:none;
}
.test {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.block').addClass('dn');

$('.test').mouseover(function() {
    $('.block').addClass('db').removeClass('dn');
});

$('.test').mouseleave(function() {
    if($('.block').attr('class') == 'block db') {
        $('.block').addClass('dn').removeClass('db');
    }
});

$('.block').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.block').addClass('dn').removeClass('db');
});
```

Помогите настроить правильную работу этих двух, вот что я хочу

При наведении на класс test, показать див .block, если отвести мышку от test то скрыть див .block, если мышку навести на test и после навести на див .block то он должен оставаться активным, и если отвести мышку от див .block то скрыть его, а в моем примере не получается навести мышку на див блок, рад буду любому красивому решению данной задаче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `.block(display absolute)` положить в `.test`